# Unable to access windows (error mounting/dev/sda4/media/ubuntu/windows)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, ntfs

Hey guys so the other day my laptop updated to 8.1. After install it required a restart, i clicked yes and now its been stuck in an infinite preparing start up repair. 
So i installed ubuntu to USB booted from that in a hopes to access my windows partition through that and copy everything off. However every time I try access the drive it gives me "the NTFS partition is in an unsafe state please resume and shutdown windows fully"

I've tried running several sudo commands but none seem to be working!

any help appreciated.

the command being

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/new

sudo mount -t ntfs -3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda1 /mnt/new
```

the error being

```
the NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. please resume and shutdown windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting) or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 1):

actually its an issue with windows 8.1 that by default it goes to hibernation instead of shutting down.
the solution for me was....

going to "Control panel" -> Power options -> check "show unavailable options" -> uncheck "FastBoot (recommended)" -> save and restart to ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

that is due to hybrid shutdown in windows , If it is possible to go to recovery menu and restart it from cmd (restart not shutdown as shutdown leaves partitions unreadable ) 
you can try this on recovery cmd prompt

```
shutdown /s /f /t 0
```

also if that is not possible then from Ubuntu try to mount partition as read only so you can copy all your files

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -ro  /dev/sda /mnt/winpart
```

change **/dev/sda** and **/mnt/winpart** as per your specific details